# How to play audio songs one after other which is placed in resources folder in iphone

Tags: iphone

I am new to iphone.I am working on audio player here i am struck in the middle because i am facing some issue that is here in my project i have 2 directories in resource folder.In each directory i have 6mp3 audio files.So my issue is when user gives the path to the 3rd mp3 song in first directory in resources folder from that we have to play continuous all the songs like 4th,5th,6th mp3files also which is placed in that directory in resources folder.here is my code for this

```
    NSString *chapterString =@"3";
    NSString *string = [[NSBundle mainBundle]pathForResource:chapterString ofType:@"mp3" inDirectory:@"raj"];
    NSLog(@"string is %@",string);
    url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:string isDirectory:YES];
    NSError *error;
    audioPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc]initWithContentsOfURL:url error:&error];
```

If any body know this please help me..

Answer (score 0):

You could get the contents of the directories into an Array via `NSFileManager`, upon finishing song x..play the next song in the array, song y.

Answer (score 0):

1. Put all the songs in an array
2. Initialize a global variable suppose x
3. Write the following AVAudioPlayer Delegate

   ```
   - (void)audioPlayerDidFinishPlaying:(AVAudioPlayer *)player successfully:(BOOL)flag{
       if (x<([_downloadedSongArray count]-1)) 
       {
           x=x+1;
           [self loadSong];
       }
   }
   - (void)loadSong 
   {
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
       _audioDocumentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
       _audioDocumentsDirectory = [_audioDocumentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Songs"];
       NSString *selectedSong = [_downloadedSongArray objectAtIndex:x];
       _sharerDownloadedString=selectedSong;
       selectedSong = [selectedSong stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
       _audioDocumentsDirectory = [_audioDocumentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:selectedSong];

       url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:_audioDocumentsDirectory];
       [_audio stop];
       _audio = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url error:nil];
       [_audio prepareToPlay];
       [_audio play];
       [Utility setPlaying:YES];
       [_audio setDelegate:self];
   }
   ```

Where _downloadedSongArray is an array where all song are. And loadSong is a method which load next/prev song from an array based on index and assign to the AVAudioPlayer.